# how do I declare a variable outside a public static function in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to declare a variable outside a public class in PHP, but for some reason, it does not work.

Here is my code

```
$catID = '33234532';

    public static function saveFile($name, $catID){
    $name = 'catid_' . $catID . time() . '_' . '.' . pathinfo(saveFiles:sanitizeFileName($name), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    ... rest of my code
    }
```

now, when I save the file I get catid__1487393557.png, it completely ignores the $catID.

Now, when I do this below it outputs the right thing.

```
    public static function saveFile($name, $catID){
    $catID = '33234532';

    $name = 'catid_' . $catID . time() . '_' . '.' . pathinfo(saveFiles:sanitizeFileName($name), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    ... rest of my code
    }
```

This outputs this: catid_33234532_1487393557.png

Comment: It is a good idea to rethink your suggested design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try global variable to declare variable outside function

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have same variable name in your code may be. when your code is executing it it taking the value of $catID from the function parameter.

Secondly you need to call the variable as global while you are gonna call it in the function. something like following...

```
$catID = '33234532';
function saveFile($name){
   echo 'catid_' . $GLOBALS['catID'];
}
```